# Matrix with no negative elements = Positive Semi Definite?

Tags: positive-semidefinite

A matrix $A$ is positive semi-definite IFF $x^TAx\geq 0$ for all non-zero $x\in\mathbb{R}^d$. If all elements of $A$ are non-negative, does this guarantee that $A$ is positive semi-definite?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

No.  The matrix $A=\begin{pmatrix}0&1\\1&0\end{pmatrix}$ is not psd, as you can check by seeing that $(1,-1)A(1,-1)^T=-2$.

Answer (score 2):

$$
\left(
\begin{array}{cc}
1 & 153 \\
153 & 1
\end{array}
\right)
$$

Answer (score 2):

In general no. One way of defining positive definiteness is through the leading principal minors of a matrix. The $k^{th}$ leading minor if found by computing the deturminant of the matrix after deleting the last $n-k$ colomns and rows in an $n \times n $ matrix. It is quite common to see a matrix with all positive entries that has a negative deturminnant, this therefore means this matrix would not be positive definite. For example, If you look at the leading principal minors of the following matrix $ A \in \mathbb{R}^{n\times n}$:

$$ A = \left( \begin{array}{cc}
1 & 1 \\ 2 & 1
\end{array}\right),$$

for $A$ to be positive definite $det(1)>0$ and $det(A)>0$. This is clearly not the case as $det(A)=-1$. In fact this particular matrix is indefinite.